# Creating a game of multilingual scrabble in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file **scrabble_letters.txt** which reads as following:

```
1 E  
1 A  
1 I  
1 N  
1 O  
... etc
```

I need to write a program to help me score each word, reading in the points for each letter from scrabble_letters.txt, which looks like this:

```
Word: kiwi
11 points
```

Here's an example when scrabble_letters.txt uses the scores from the letter scores from the **French version of Scrabble**:

```
Word: kiwi
22 points
```

So far I am able to compile a rough program (does not function as intended) as follows:

```
f = open('scrabble_letters.txt')
for line in f:
  SCORES = (line.strip())

  total = 0
  def scrabble_score(word):
    total = ()
  Word = input("Word: ")
  for letter in Word:
          total += SCORES[letter]
  print (total, "points")
```

I am stuck here and just not sure how to create output from a French version of Scrabble or how it works.

Comment: Why do you mention so specifically french version? Is there any link between text files? Or you just want a sum of scores from the text file according to the input word?

Comment: indent your code correctly - its broken.

Comment: Your code is completely language-agnostic. It's the contents of `scrabble_letters.txt` that determines which language's scoring rules will evaluate the word. One fix would be to have the user enter which language to use, and use that input to decide what scoring file to open.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I tried several ways but still no avail.

Comment: @chepner your view sounds logical to me, however, I am not that intelligent enough to figure out   **language's scoring rules will evaluate the word**

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a file 'scrabble_letters.txt' which contains the scores for each letter, then below code defines a method `scrabble_score()` which takes a word as an argument and prints the score of the word.

```
f = open('scrabble_letters.txt')
scores = {}
# make a map of letter to its score. Important: note the type casting to integer.
for line in f:
    temp = line.strip()
# line.split() takes a line eg. "1 K" and returns an array ['1', 'K'] i.e. splits by spaces.
    temp = line.split()
    scores[temp[1]] = int(temp[0])

def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0
    for letter in word:
        total += scores[letter]
    print (total, "points")
```

For a sample text file:

```
1 E  
1 A  
1 I  
1 N  
1 O 
5 K
6 W
```

Running the method as

```
scrabble_score('KIWI')
```

prints the output `13 points`

P.S: The scoring version (as you mentioned french in the question) is purely dependent on contents of `scrabble_letters.txt`. You have an option of opening the desired file depending on condition using `if-else` block

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I am taking a coding class and that requires me to get answer in that exact form. However I was able to get desired output by using two different values for **scrabble_letters.txt**  I am just not sure how it works for both with same program to show two different outputs.

Comment: you mean a single file giving two different scores?

Comment: I guess so, that's why they say **scrabble_letters.txt** uses the scores from the _letter scores_ from the French version of Scrabble. I am able to get the desired outputs with two different programs but not the same one, I'm just confused.

Comment: Reading your question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735515/does-this-python-multilingual-scrabble-scorer-makes-any-sense here. Your assignment just asks you to use the input file and print the score. You can stop caring about the French or English version. According to question that is not your concern. You just need to open the file "scrabble_letters.txt" and give scores.

Comment: I did, and was able to get desired outputs with different codes but not the same code as I am required to do.

Comment: Are you submitting on an online judge? If yes then please share an example input/output test case and if not then I am pretty sure those different scores are just for example purpose. (According to the wording of your question)